# Duplicating a Neo field's content

Tags: structure, plugin-neo

I'm writing a plugin to duplicate a Structure within Craft 2.
I've covered off duplicating the section, entry types, field layouts and can duplicate the entries, covering of the main Craft fields.

However I'm completely stumped on duplicating a Neo field. I've figured out to access all the field types and content within the Neo blocks, but can't get the Neo field to validate for the new Entry.

Right now, I'm considering dumping the SQL and using that because I've tried everything else!